# atom fail to start a terminal due to nuclide

Tags: python, linux, npm, atom-editor

I'm trying to set up the atom editor as an ide for python development on linux, and I've installed the following packages:

```
Community Packages (14) [home path]/.atom/packages
├── Hydrogen@2.14.1
├── atom-file-icons@0.7.1
├── atom-ide-ui@0.13.0
├── atom-material-syntax-light@0.4.6
├── autocomplete-python@1.16.0
├── busy-signal@2.0.1
├── hydrogen-python@0.0.8
├── ide-python@1.5.0
├── intentions@1.1.5
├── linter@2.3.1 (disabled)
├── linter-flake8@2.4.0
├── linter-ui-default@1.8.1
├── minimap@4.29.9
└── python-autopep8@0.1.3
```

and when i try to start a terminal from "view --> terminal --> start new terminal" i get the following error:

```
For more info check out the docs: https://nuclide.io/docs/features/terminal
Error starting process:
Error: Cannot find module '[home path]/.atom/packages/atom-ide-ui/node_modules/nuclide-prebuilt-libs/pty/build/pty-node-v69-linux-x64/pty.node'
```

I've searched the error and i think it's a version mismatch.

after a lot of searching and getting nothing i tried to create that folder and copy the "pty.node" from "pty-node-v57-linux-x64" but the terminal fail anyway and return the error:

```
For more info check out the docs: https://nuclide.io/docs/features/terminal
Error starting process:
Error: The module '[home path]/.atom/packages/atom-ide-ui/node_modules/nuclide-prebuilt-libs/pty/build/pty-node-v69-linux-x64/pty.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

so i searched and tried some random things like:

```
$ cd [home path].atom/packages/atom-ide-ui/node_modules/nuclide-prebuilt-libs/pty/build
$ node -p process.versions.modules
57
$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 5.3.0-40-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! pty@0.0.0 prepublish: `npm run tsc && cp src/index.js.flow lib/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pty@0.0.0 prepublish script 'npm run tsc && cp src/index.js.flow lib/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the pty package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run tsc && cp src/index.js.flow lib/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs pty
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls pty
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     [home path].atom/packages/atom-ide-ui/node_modules/nuclide-prebuilt-libs/pty/build/npm-debug.log
```

and other useless things.

I'm totally new to npm so i don't know how to interpret properly those outputs.

any idea to solve this? or any alternative packages to set up atom as a python ide?

Comment: Running into same issue i found somthing like this but doesnt looks like a fix yet https://github.com/facebookarchive/atom-ide-ui/issues/241

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This is my environment:

```
❯ apm -v                  
apm  2.5.2
npm  6.14.8
node 12.4.0 x64
atom 1.54.0
python 
git 2.27.0
```

So, I went to `~/.atom/packages/atom-ide-ui` and reviewed the `package.json` file to notice `atom-ide-ui` is using `nuclide-prebuilt-libs@0.5.2`. So, I installed the latest version of `nuclide-prebuilt-libs`, which, at the moment of writing, is `0.6.3`:

```
❯ npm install nuclide-prebuilt-libs@0.6.3
```

After that, opening the terminal (`ctrl+shift+t`) works like a charm.

Comment: didn't work for me got the same issue after installing 0.6.3 and restarting, almost the same configuration `apm  2.6.2
npm  6.14.13
node 12.14.1 x64
atom 1.59.0-beta0
python 3.8.6
git 2.31.1.windows.1
visual studio 2019`